# Flask Testing in Python -- Building one API in a repo with many to unit test it via import_module

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

We have an ETL data API repo. We do all etl processing inside of it, then spit the data out in API's. These API's are run one at a time from a single command passing the resource class through to the server to build an API. the resource class is in a web directory in an `__init__.py.`

This is a wonderful convention and quite simple to use, but the problem I am having is coming from trying to get one of the 3 API's available spun up for testing. Our directory stucture is like this (calling the project 'tomato')

```
tomato

- category_api
    - web
    - etl
    - test
        - here is where we are writing some tests (test_category_api.py)
    - data
- article_api
    - web
    - etl
    - test
    - data
- recommendation_api
    - web
    - etl
    - test
    - data
- common
    - common shit
```

Inside this test, I have the following test class. On the seventh line up from the bottom, 
you will see a comment on where it breaks. It is the `import_module` method.

```
    import unittest
    import sys
    import os
    import sys
    import json

    from importlib import import_module
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_restful import Api, abort, wraps
    from flask_restful.utils import cors
    from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

    #dir_above_top_level = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '../../..    /')
    #sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(dir_above_top_level))

    _CATEGORY_ENDPOINT = '/v1/category/'
    _PACKAGE_NAME = os.environ['RECO_API_PACKAGE_NAME']
    _CORS = cors.crossdomain(origin='*',
                             headers=['Origin', 'X-Requested-With',
                                      'Content-Type', 'Accept'],
                             methods=['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                             max_age=3600)

    class CategoryTests(TestCase):
        def __init__(self):
            self.app = Flask(__name__)
            self._configure_app()
            for resource in self.resource_classes:
                self.api.add_resource(self.resource,
                                      self.resource.URI_TEMPLATE)
        def test_status_code(self):
            self.response = self.client.post(_CATEGORY_ENDPOINT,
                                         data=json.dumps(
                                         {'title': 'Enjoy this delicious food'}),
                                         headers=json.dumps(
                                         {'content-type':'application/json'}))
            self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)

        def test_version(self):
            self.response = self.client.post(_CATEGORY_ENDPOINT,
                                             data=json.dumps(
                                             {"title": "eat some delicious stuff"}),
                                             headers=json.dumps(
                                             {'content-type':'application/json'}))
            self.assertEqual(json.dumps(self.response['version']), '1')

        def _configure_app(self):
            self.app = Flask(__name__)
            self.app.config['TESTING'] = True
            self.app.debug = True
            self.decorators = [_CORS]
            self.app.Threaded = True
            self.web_package = 'tomato.category.web'
            self.package = import_module('.__init__', self.web_package) # WE BREAK HERE
            self.resources = package.RESOURCE_NAMES
            self.resource_classes = [ getattr(package, resource) for resource in resources ]
            self.api = Api(self.app, catch_all_404s=True, decorators=self.decorators)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main()
```

we are given an exception when running these tests:

`ImportError: No module named tomato.category.web.__init__`

yet cd into the main top dir, and `ls tomato/category/web` gets us `__init__.py` and its right there with the resource class.

How do I import this class so that I can instantiate the API to run the tests in this class?
Or if I'm completely on the wrong track what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import `__init__`, just like you probably wouldn't do `from tomato.category.web import __init__`. You should be able to import the `web` package directly.

```
self.web_package = 'tomato.category.web'
self.package = import_module(self.web_package)
```

Comment: Do you mean `import_module` instead of `import_lib`? I figured as much so I changed it to that (import_lib didnt exist w/the imports i was using in any way). I did however run this exactly as stated and I got the output:

        File `"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
        ImportError: No module named tomato.category.web`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: If `solomon` isn't the real name of `tomato`, that's your problem. Assuming it is, though, it sounds like `solomon` isn't in your path. How and from what directory are you running your tests?

Comment: No problem, I appreciate the response! Sadly, I'm still getting the error referenced in the prior comment when I run it that way. Ugh. Could this be something to do with the current abspath or something where it would not see it?

Comment: I was using a fake name for the repo, the real name is solomon. editing.

Comment: test directory is tomoato/api_name/test/api_name_tests.py each API is run individually so they have individualized unit tests inside the dir and acceptance tests for already-running staging API's in the main repo's test dir

Comment: Is this essentially how you're running your tests? `$ cd tomato/api_name/test; python api_name_tests.py`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67254/discussion-between-dirn-and-devbob).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies in the directory structure. In the current path, I am not at the top level. It is a module. So What was needed was to uncomment the line two lines at the top, and change the structure to append the path like this.

```
dir_above_top_level = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), '../../../..')
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(dir_above_top_level))
```

and now, I can import it using

```
self.web_package = 'tomato.category.web'
self.package = import_module('.__init__', self.web_package)
```

and now it will import fine and I can grab the resource class to set up the testing API